# Remove the Index from Dataframe (stock data)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to remove the index on the left from the Table.
I did:

```
import pandas as pd
nv.to_csv('H:/XYZfile/nvidia.csv', index=False)
```

Then

```
nv.head()
```

and I still get the index:
[image: 1]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the saved csv directly. There won’t be an index :)

Answer (score 0):

that's your index , if you want to set another column as index , you can do:

```
nv.set_index('Date')
```

but thta's only in your dataframe , in your csv you won't see that since you are passing index = false